# FFMPEG CONCAT Error

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I need help about ffmpeg concat. Please help me !

I have 3 video, and i want join it with concat.

Demo File : list.txt

```
file 'a.mp4'
file 'b.mp4'
file 'c.mp4'
```

Demo File : join.bat

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i "list.txt" -codec copy "join.mp4"
```

But i get error :

```
ffmpeg version N-81863-gcced839 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 60.101 / 57. 60.101
  libavformat    57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 63.100 /  6. 63.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[concat @ 00000000024524a0] Line 1: unknown keyword '∩╗┐file'
list.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I think my computer error. Because, this code working in my laptop.
Please help me to fix it for can working on my computer :(

Comment: Issue looks like [#3718 ffmpeg does not correctly read input text file](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3718). Ensure that `list.txt` does not contain errant data. I recently saw another user with an invisible Unicode character in the command which was causing a similar issue (but not using concat).

Comment: Thanks so much. It work. But get another error :(

Comment: I wonder what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe file list.txt have BOM "Byte order mark" (UTF8-BOM) prefix (text encoding) HEX:"\xEF\xBBx\BF" in file begin - it's have eroor.

You have in file begin: BOM+text : "\xEF\xBBx\BFfile 'a.mp4'\n".

You need in file begin: text     : "file 'a.mp4'\n".

You need try encode file list.txt to ASCII text encoding, or remove BOM prefix.